# Notation of a vector field

Tags: vector-analysis

Usually vector field looks like $\sum_{i} a_i(x_1,x_2,...x_n) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, also it is not a problem to write it like that $\sum_{i}a_i\partial_i$ or even $a^i\partial_i$ using Einstein notation. However i cannot understand a formulation of a problem, where we are to consider all such vector fields that satisfy the equation: $\partial_iu_j+\partial_ju_i=0$, where $u_i$ are the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (original words from the problem sheet). What does that mean?

Comment: It could mean that the vector field $\sum u_i\partial_i$ satisfies this condition.
You may get a hint about this if you look at what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @GustavoMarra's interpretation is almost certainly correct. The equation $\partial_i u_j + \partial_j u_i = 0$ for the coefficients of a vector field $\sum u_i \partial_i$ is [Killing's equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KillingsEquation.html) of the Euclidean metric.